Rails devcontainer can't pull ruby image
I have a Rails 7.2 app, and I'd like to start using devcontainer, so I have generated the necessary files with rails devcontainer, which generated the .devcontainer folder and the three needed files.
After that, from my VS Code I opened the Command Palette and run Dev Containers: Reopen in Container but I get the following error from the remote container.
[2024-09-04T14:14:13.708Z] Start: Run: docker inspect --type image ghcr.io/rails/devcontainer/images/ruby:3.3.5
[2024-09-04T14:14:13.783Z] Stop (75 ms): Run: docker inspect --type image ghcr.io/rails/devcontainer/images/ruby:3.3.5
[2024-09-04T14:14:13.784Z] Loading 4 extra certificates from /var/folders/hn/rjpjxq957hvdsyvgmn8km5bh0000gn/T/vsch/certificates-6226df7ef35e370fb810c6e077b2acfe61fdc85694eefd1e9531615cdc5ec891.pem.
[2024-09-04T14:14:13.953Z] Start: Run: docker-credential-desktop get
[2024-09-04T14:14:14.204Z] Stop (251 ms): Run: docker-credential-desktop get
[2024-09-04T14:14:14.402Z] [httpOci] 403: Credentials for 'ghcr.io' may be expired. Attempting request anonymously.
[2024-09-04T14:14:14.402Z] {"errors":[{"code":"DENIED","message":"denied"}]}
.
[2024-09-04T14:14:14.915Z] Error fetching image details: No manifest found for ghcr.io/rails/devcontainer/images/ruby:3.3.5.
[2024-09-04T14:14:14.916Z] Start: Run: docker pull ghcr.io/rails/devcontainer/images/ruby:3.3.5
[2024-09-04T14:14:15.608Z] Error response from daemon: Head "https://ghcr.io/v2/rails/devcontainer/images/ruby/manifests/3.3.5": denied: denied
[2024-09-04T14:14:15.615Z] Stop (699 ms): Run: docker pull ghcr.io/rails/devcontainer/images/ruby:3.3.5
[2024-09-04T14:14:15.615Z] []
[2024-09-04T14:14:15.615Z] Error response from daemon: No such image: ghcr.io/rails/devcontainer/images/ruby:3.3.5

[2024-09-04T14:14:15.616Z] Error: Command failed: docker inspect --type image ghcr.io/rails/devcontainer/images/ruby:3.3.5
[2024-09-04T14:14:15.616Z]     at utA (/Users/sig/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.380.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:410:3925)
[2024-09-04T14:14:15.616Z]     at async KtA (/Users/sig/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.380.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:482:3944)
[2024-09-04T14:14:15.616Z]     at async eB (/Users/sig/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.380.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:482:4886)
[2024-09-04T14:14:15.616Z]     at async hrA (/Users/sig/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.380.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:663:200)
[2024-09-04T14:14:15.616Z]     at async lrA (/Users/sig/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.380.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js:662:13452)
[2024-09-04T14:14:15.625Z] Stop (3150 ms): Run: /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code Helper (Plugin).app/Contents/MacOS/Code Helper (Plugin) /Users/sig/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.380.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js up --user-data-folder /Users/sig/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers/data --container-session-data-folder /tmp/devcontainers-db48fc8f-d6ce-46cb-9ec8-278cb712092c1725459250845 --workspace-folder /Users/sig/Code/stage-three --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=/Users/sig/Code/stage-three --id-label devcontainer.config_file=/Users/sig/Code/stage-three/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --log-level debug --log-format json --config /Users/sig/Code/stage-three/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default on --mount-workspace-git-root --include-configuration --include-merged-configuration
[2024-09-04T14:14:15.625Z] Exit code 1
[2024-09-04T14:14:15.630Z] Command failed: /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code Helper (Plugin).app/Contents/MacOS/Code Helper (Plugin) /Users/sig/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.380.0/dist/spec-node/devContainersSpecCLI.js up --user-data-folder /Users/sig/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers/data --container-session-data-folder /tmp/devcontainers-db48fc8f-d6ce-46cb-9ec8-278cb712092c1725459250845 --workspace-folder /Users/sig/Code/stage-three --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=/Users/sig/Code/stage-three --id-label devcontainer.config_file=/Users/sig/Code/stage-three/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --log-level debug --log-format json --config /Users/sig/Code/stage-three/.devcontainer/devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default on --mount-workspace-git-root --include-configuration --include-merged-configuration
[2024-09-04T14:14:15.630Z] Exit code 1

What am I missing here?

Many similar posts and issues seem to suggest trying docker logout ghcr.io. Since the images are public you should just be able to try again (without the need to log back in)
